# $x(t) = e^{\sin t}$ and $y(t) = 2\cos t$. What is $\frac{dy}{dx}$?

Tags: derivatives

$x(t) = e^{\sin t}$ and $y(t) = 2\cos t$. What is $\frac{dy}{dx}$?

I think the chain-rule is applied here.

Comment: What is $$\frac{d}{dx} 2\cos\arcsin\log x$$ ?

Answer (score 2):

**hint**: $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{\dfrac{dy}{dt}}{\dfrac{dx}{dt}}$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, though I am not sure how dx/dt relates to dt/dx.

Comment: they are reciprocal of each other

Comment: @DeepSea Though you need y to be invertable for this result to hold right? And it’s its inverse must be diffrentiable

Answer (score 0):

Hint $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{(dy/dt)}{(dx/dt)}$$ now it can be done easily

Answer (score 0):

Using the chain rule
$$\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac {dy}{dt}\times\frac{dt}{dx}=$$

> $$-2\sin(t)\times{1\over\cos(t)e^{\sin(t)}}$$

Note :
$$\frac {dx}{dt}\times\frac{dt}{dx}=1 $$